# Which paypal service should I use

Tags: paypal

In my web application (spring mvc + jsp), I have to implement payment process which I will take the money of someone (i.e buyer), deposit to someone else (i.e seller), and keep a portion for myself (i.e commission). I would like the process will perform on my website instead of redirecting to paypal. I have tried to search for the service that I need, but after a while of reading it, I am very confused. I am thinking I may need some mix between Adaptive Payment or Website Payment Pro. However, I think that Paypal would also provide a service that I am searching for, but I haven't found yet. So would anyone mind to help me out of this confusion please?

Comment: I would like to get some feed back even though it may not the answer I want to hear. It must be better than a negative vote but silent comment. Would that action help other to learn?

Comment: I think you're getting downvotes because this question is too broad for this site and is generally asking about details of and opinions on different elements of the Paypal API, rather than a specific programming problem (e.g. I tried to use X API using Y code, I expected to be able to do Z, but it didn't work - can anyone explain?).  Usually questions like that get closed on this site, so people have probably downvoted because of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do the payment split as part of checkout you would need to use Adaptive Payments, specifically the Pay API with a chained payment.  Unfortunately, you can't avoid redirecting the user to PayPal with this method.

If that's a must, then you'll need to go with Payments Pro, but then you can't do the split within a single checkout, and you can't split the fees up among the receivers.  So you'll end up paying a fee when you receive the money, and then when you send the money there will be another fee there, too.  Also, if you go that route you would be responsible for any chargebacks that occur, so this is simply not recommended.

Comment: Thank you for clarify it to me. It helped me to pick the service I need.